# UI Bootstrap - how to stop tooltip showing changed text before closing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a tooltip working on a glyphicon. When I click on the glyphicon I want to hide the tooltip, and then change the text of the tooltip. This reflects a change in state for the glyphicon which has been clicked.

However, when I hide the tooltip and then change the text of the tooltip, instead of doing it in this order, for a second you can see the new text in the tooltip before it disappears.

Here is the html:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open watch-eye"
    ng-click="eyeClicked()" uib-tooltip="{{watchTooltip}}"
    tooltip-placement="auto top" tooltip-is-open="eyeTooltipIsOpen">
</span>
```

And here is javascript:

```
$scope.watchingCategory = false;
$scope.watchTooltip = 'Watch';

$scope.eyeClicked = function() {

    $scope.eyeTooltipIsOpen = !$scope.eyeTooltipIsOpen;
    $scope.watchingCategory = !$scope.watchingCategory;

    if($scope.watchingCategory === true) {
        $scope.watchTooltip = 'Dont watch';
    }
    else if($scope.watchingCategory === false) {
        $scope.watchTooltip = 'Watch';
    }
};
```

I've created a plnkr to show exactly how it is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/myQlkkiSNO14td21Dv0M

Any ideas how to stop this behaviour? All help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a problem whitin the uib directive.

A timeout solves the problem :

```
 $timeout(function(){
        $scope.watchTooltip = $scope.watchingCategory ?  'Dont watch' : 'Watch';
    }, 200);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/myQlkkiSNO14td21Dv0M?p=preview

Comment: Hi gr3g - thanks for that - it works just fine!  Tom